# let's encrypt https certificate for Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, https, tls1.2, lets-encrypt, minikube

I'm following some useful tutorials on how to set https certificates for Minikube ingresses.

The thing I've noted are:

- they always use ngrok paid service and tunneling to have a public domain to be certificated by Let's Encrypt;
- else Let's Encrypt is not used and, as a matter of example for a local Minikube distribution, a self signed certificate is used instead.

My question is: is there a way to use Let's Encrypt with a local Minikube in a non-paid version?
For example using Katacoda or other free session tools?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking for. Minikube is free, Let's Encrypt is also free. Katacoda is a learning platform which can be also used as a lab.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to use Let's Encrypt to expose an kubernetes ingress with https in your local Environment using minikube where you don't have a real public domain name.

Comment: Why don't you use self signed cert if the domain is not real?

Comment: I wanted to use an external issuer because is more similar to a production case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any organization that would issue you a certificate without verifying the domain.

You need to understand that in order to get a certificate a global Certificate Authority (CA) needs to validate if you have access to the domain for which certificate is being requested.

There is an article about [Certificates for localhost](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/), but still you need to create those yourself.

There is also few pages in Kubernetes docs about [Certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/) which you can generate yourself manually using easyrsa, openssl or cfssl. Also [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/).

Check out this tutorial on Gardener about [Request X.509 Certificates](https://gardener.cloud/documentation/050-tutorials/content/howto/x509_certificates/) and [HTTPS with self Signed Certificate](https://gardener.cloud/documentation/050-tutorials/content/app/https/).

You can read [How to get HTTPS working on your local development environment in 5 minutes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/) which explains how to self-sign and setup a cert for `localhost`.